# Python/google app engine/bootstrap popup input dialog

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Google App Engine application (in Python!) with Facebook login that is based on the example [here](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py). When a user logs in, this [example.html](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.html) takes care of the display (in my case, a nice list of the user's Facebook friends and some of their information extracted from the graph API).

Before (or right after) the standard Facebook login box comes up, I want another popup box that prompts the user to choose whether they want to display male friends or female friends. In other words, the might see this as usual:

[image: standard FB app login popup]

...followed by something like this:2

[image: simple two-choice dialog box]

...The other way around would be fine too (preference box and then FB box); the goal is to store the "guy or gal" preference as an attribute of my User class (just as the Facebook login lets me gather the other attributes), which extends from the one in the [example.py](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py) :

```
...
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    profile_url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    access_token = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    preferred_gender = db.StringProperty(required=True) ####### ADDED #########
...
```

My understanding of the current flow of things is that the `HomeHandler`in example.py leads to a rendering of the main.html, which displays the login button that calls this upon being clicked:

```
function doLogin() {  
                 FB.login(function(response) {} , {perms:'...'}); 
}
```

...So, I'm assuming the dialog I want would be called/displayed from somewhere in there. Since I'm pretty new to Javascript, Bootstrap (which I am using as a framework for my pages), and the web in general, how, and with what tools (e.g., Bootstrap...and more JS, perhaps?) can I coordinate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FB login will direct the user away from your site, to FB, so they can log in (this way you can't see the password they type in).

After they log in, they are redirected back to your site.

In your example.html, there's some sections:

```
{% if current_user %}
  <p><a href="{{ current_user.profile_url }}"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{ current_user.id }}/picture?type=square"/></a></p>
  <p>Hello, {{ current_user.name|escape }}</p>
{% endif %}

<div id="fb-root"></div>

{% if current_user %}
        <div>
        Upload photo test: 
               <form method="post">
               Enter URL to URLFetch from:<input type="text" name="url"/>
               <input type="submit"/>
               </form>
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

These parts of the page don't show up when the user is not logged in, however, when they are redirected back to this page after logging in, those parts of the page are filled in.  So you might replace that "Upload photo test" with a Bootstrap modal.

```
{% if current_user %}
    <div id="modal-question" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>I want to see</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Guys</p>
        <p>Gals</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn secondary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $('#modal-question').modal('show');
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

Make sure you have jquery and the Bootstrap modal script included.

Comment: I have included jquery and the Bootstrap modal script (to my understanding, that means putting the corresponding lines at the end of the file, near the closing `</body>` tag, right?) and tried your example exactly as shown. But nothing pops up at all.

Comment: My example might not be perfect.  Any javascript errors being reported?  You have this running where I can try it to see what's wrong?